# How to get a result from search even if the search query contains a part of title?

Tags: entries, search

Suppose there are three Entries:

- Entry One
- Section One
- Channel One

I need to get `Section One` in result when I search **Sect**. Is this possible ? I am using

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query) %}
```

to get the results. But keyword `sect` doesn't return any result.

Answer (score 2):

Like stated in the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching) you have to place `*` around your search term

```
{% set results = craft.entries({
    search: {
        query: '*sect*',
        subLeft: true,
        subRight: true                
    }
}) %}
```

Note: it would be easier to help you if you show us your `query` variable